# HTML not lining up

Tags: html, css

https://www.citywidelaw.com/

For this page, there is a section with a Q and A (you click on question and answer is next to it. The Q symbol and A symbol are supposed to line-up. I'm not sure why the A is dropping. I tried a , but it had no effect.

I added an image. Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div id="verticalTab" class="resp-vtabs" style="display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0px;">
<h2 class="resp-vtabs-heading">
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
<div class="resp-tabs-container">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.resp-vtabs .resp-tabs-container {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    min-height: 350px;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
    width: 53%;
}
.resp-tabs-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: left;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Q" symbol, the `<h2>` element, is an element above the two columns.[image: Original]

So here's what I would do. Create a `<div>` element around the `<h2>` and `<ul>` elements with a class of, say, `resp-tabs-list-container`. Then just rename, in your CSS, the selector `.resp-vtabs ul.resp-tabs-list` to `.resp-vtabs .resp-tabs-list-container`.

Pow.

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this answer!